# Covert a string expression to numerical value in python

Tags: python, string

Recently, I got an interview question which says to convert string expressions like "1+2-3" and "-2+4" to 0 and 2 respectively. Assuming the inputs are single digits numbers followed by signs and no NULL input. I tried this output but the interviewer said I am close but not perfect solution. Please help me here. Thanks.

```
def ans(input):
    result, j = 0, 0
    for i in input:
        if i == '+' or i == '-':
            j = i
        else:
            i = int(i)
            result = result j i
    return result       
ans("1+2-3")
ans("-2+4")
```

I am making some silly mistake but I am learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, naming variables `str` is considered very bad form, as it shadows the Python built-in string constructor, `str`, which means you can't stringify things for as long as the local `str` remains in scope.

Comment: Made the updates. Thanks.

Comment: `input` is a Python built-in function too (though admittedly a less commonly used one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things *need* fixing to work at all:

1. You need to handle the initial value properly; when the initial value is non-negative, this fails. Before the loop, set `j = '+'` so a non-sign prefixed value is added (also, for style points, `j` is a terrible name, could you use `op` or something?).
2. You can't use variables as operators.

Replace:

```
result = result j i
```

with:

```
if j == '+':
    result += i
else:
    result -= i
```

Note: If modules are allowed, a generalization can be used to handle operators the "nice" way (though more work would be needed to obey operator precedence). You'd define:

```
import operator

ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, ...}
```

then make the initial value of `op` `operator.add` and change the test for operators to:

```
if i in ops:
    op = ops[i]
else:
    result = op(result, int(i))
```

which scales to many more operators, dynamically selecting the operation to perform without cascading `if`/`elif` checks.

Side-note: While violating the spirit of the challenge, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (at least as of Python 3.5, and this may change, see [bug #22525](http://bugs.python.org/issue22525)) will actually safely parse strings like this (`eval` is unsafe, since it can execute arbitrary code, but `ast.literal_eval` can only parse Python literals and apparently some basic compile-time math). So you could just do:

```
import ast

ans = ast.literal_eval
```

Sure, it handles many other literals too, but we never defined the failure case behavior anyway. :-)

Comment: The result I my getting in the first case is -2 instead of 0. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @deep: You must have an indentation or other error somewhere. I ran your exact code with my modifications and it came up with `0` and `2`.

Comment: is this right way: if j == '+':
                result += i
            elif j == '-':
                result -= i
            else:
                result = i

Comment: You don't need the second test. If you initialize `j = '+'` before the loop begins, then `j` can only be `+` or `-`, nothing else. The code I gave in my numbered list is enough: Initialize `j` before the loop, and have a single `if`/`else` to handle the only possible `j` values, `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **eval()** is the simplest solution. Like

```
eval("1+2-3")
```

The following code give another solution without using built-in **eval**

```
import operator


class Parse(object):
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.pos = 0
        self.end = len(input)

    def eval(self):
        result = self.match_digits()

        while self.pos < self.end:
            op = self.match_operator()
            operand = self.match_digits()
            result = op(result, operand)
        return result

    def match_operator(self):
        look_ahead = self.input[self.pos]
        self.advance()
        return operator.add if look_ahead == '+' else operator.sub

    def match_digits(self):
        look_ahead = self.input[self.pos]

        positive = 1
        if look_ahead == '-':
            positive = -1
            self.advance()

        digits, s = 0, self.pos
        while s < self.end and self.input[s].isdigit():
            digits = digits * 10 + int(self.input[s])
            s += 1
        self.advance(s-self.pos)
        return digits * positive

    def advance(self, offset=1):
        self.pos += offset
```

For testing

```
p = Parse(input='2+1+0-3')
print p.eval()

p = Parse(input='-2+-13+3')
print p.eval()
```

Comment: Not using any "python buildins". Any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most flexible solution (not using `eval` and able to handle any operations) is to parse the string into a binary (red-black) tree, where leafs are numbers and branches operators (+,-,/,*,etc).

For example, `"1+(5*12)/17"` would be parsed into following structure:

```
       "+"
       / \
      1   "/"
         /   \
       "()"   17
       /
      "*"
      / \
     5   12
```

Once you've parsed a string into this structure, it's easy to compute by traversing branches depth-first, right to left.

If you need to handle variables, then you'd have to get `locals()` and replace accordingly, either as you parse the string, or as you traverse the tree.

EDIT:

I created a working example to illustrate this, you can find the source on github: https://github.com/MJWunderlich/py-math-expression-evaluator

Answer (score -1):

what about:

```
def f(s):
    s = s.strip()
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '+':
            return f(s[:i]) + f(s[i+1:])
        if c == '-':
            return f(s[:i]) - f(s[i+1:])
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '*':
            return f(s[:i]) * f(s[i+1:])
        if c == '/':
            return f(s[:i]) / f(s[i+1:])
    return 0 if s == '' else int(s)
```

? Doesn't work with parenthesis

Comment: Please don't name stomp/shadow on Python built-ins; there is already an `eval` function.

Comment: yeah, name it as you want. They are looking for non built in functions so not `eval`. But true better keep the namespace in order